# Using CSS setProperty for top does not work well when implement GWT drag

Tags: css, gwt, drag

I am implementing a GWT application, have a scroll panel, flow panel which contains image, mouse down/move/up to drag the flow panel in scroll panel.

Left part (x direction) works perfectly, however, the same code for top (y direction) does not work well, it seems it shake and move unstable.

Somehow the top value is much larger than left which cause the problem, but no idea how it happens and how to make the Y direction work smoothly.

```
public void mouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
    {
                isMouseDown = true;
                event.preventDefault();

                xoffset = event.getX();
                yoffset = event.getY();

                Event.setCapture(panel.getElement());
    }
      public  void mouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
            int = event.getX();
            int y = event.getY();    

            float left = panel.getAbsoluteLeft();
            float top = panel.getAbsoluteTop();

            float offset_XX = x - xoffset;
            float offset_YY = y - yoffset;


            panel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("position", "absolute");


            float newLeft = left + offset_XX;

            if (isMouseDown) {

            if (newLeft < scrollPanel.getAbsoluteLeft()   ) {


                offset_XX =   offset_XX - Math.abs(scrollPanel.getAbsoluteLeft() -panel.getAbsoluteLeft());
                if (Math.abs(offset_XX) > Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetWidth() - panel.getOffsetWidth())) {
                    if (offset_XX > 0 )
                        offset_XX = Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetWidth() - panel.getOffsetWidth());
                    else
                        offset_XX = -Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetWidth() - panel.getOffsetWidth());
                }
                panel.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("left", (int)offset_XX);
            }
            float newtop = top + offset_YY;
            if (newtop < scrollPanel.getAbsoluteTop()) {

                offset_YY =   offset_YY - Math.abs(scrollPanel.getAbsoluteTop() -panel.getAbsoluteTop());
                if (Math.abs(offset_YY) > Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight() - panel.getOffsetHeight())) {
                    if (offset_YY > 0 )
                        offset_YY = Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight() - panel.getOffsetHeight());
                    else
                        offset_YY = -Math.abs(scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight() - panel.getOffsetHeight());
                }
                panel.getElement().getStyle().setPropertyPx("top", (int)offset_YY);
            }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, there're too many computations and DOM calls going on in your drag code. I suggest you to incorporate GWT team's solution for draggable/resizable panels following the implementation of `com.google.gwt.logging.client.LoggingPopup`. It's very fast, elegant, easy to understand and use. You can get the code here https://github.com/stephenh/google-web-toolkit/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/client/LoggingPopup.java